# Improve Sum and Rank performance in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have an MS SQL table which is indexed by Item Number and Date. I need to calculate the total sum of sales for each Item Number in a range of dates (for several date ranges), like so:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATE = '2014-06-11'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2014-06-11'

INSERT INTO @Ranks
SELECT 
[ItemNumber],
Sum([Sales]),
row_number OVER (ORDER BY SUM([Sales]) DESC) AS [Rank]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY ItemNumber

-- Some logic here (not a significant effect on performance)
DELETE FROM @Ranks

SET @BeginDate = '2014-05-11'
INSERT INTO @Ranks
SELECT 
[ItemNumber],
Sum([Sales]),
row_number OVER (ORDER BY SUM([Sales]) DESC) AS [Rank]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY ItemNumber

-- Some logic here (not a significant effect on performance)
DELETE FROM @Ranks

-- Query runs several more times, at three, six, and twelve months
```

First question: is there a way I can refactor this so it only takes one query? Second, is there a better way to calculate ranking by sum? My database is large enough that this is taking several minutes to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation, so you should be able to do all this in one query:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by sales_1 desc) as rank_1,
       row_number() over (order by sales_2 desc) as rank_2,
       row_number() over (order by sales_3 desc) as rank_3,
       row_number() over (order by sales_4 desc) as rank_4
from (SELECT ItemNumber,
             Sum(case when [date] between @BeginDate1 and @EndDate1 then Sales end) as Sales_1, 
             Sum(case when [date] between @BeginDate2 and @EndDate2 then Sales end) as Sales_2,
             Sum(case when [date] between @BeginDate3 and @EndDate3 then Sales end) as Sales_3,
             Sum(case when [date] between @BeginDate4 and @EndDate4 then Sales end) as Sales_4
      WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
      GROUP BY ItemNumber
     ) t
```

Comment: +1 for great answer, but I think for the OP's sake explaining what the variables should relate to would be helpful. I'm not sure it will necessarily be obvious that you're providing the ability to efficiently give the ranking of various date ranges in a single query. So if `@BeginDate1` is a month ago and `@EndDate1` is today and `@BeginDate2` is three months ago and `@EndDate2` is today then `rank_1` will provide the item's ranking over the past month and `rank_2` will provide the item's ranking over the past three months. I'm just not sure the OP would've understood that.

Comment: The old query took almost two minutes, this turned it into 30 seconds - many thanks!